# How to override interactivePopGestureRecognizer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I have view controller containment logic in one of my screens: a container view controller is pushed on navigation controller with initial child view controller (company list) and its view. If user taps on some row then another child view controller (company details) is added and its view is show. There are more child view controller that are shown as user goes deeper.

Those child view controllers and views are added and opened with normal fromRightToLeft view transition. The problem is when user swipes back to previous page then interactivePopGestureRecognizer pops the whole container view controller regardless of its internal child view controllers.

How to have interactivePopGestureRecognizer enabled but get a callback on  container view controller and conditionally allow or deny (and perform my custom transition animation for the views of child view controllers)? Or the only way is disable it and implement pan/swipe gestures completely on my own...